# what is the difference between using execution policy and thread pool?

Tags: c++, c++17

I had this question, while learning C++.

What is the difference between using an execution policy and VS doing the same job using a thread pool? Are there any benefits of using one over the other?

```
std::atomic<int> sum{0};
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&](int i) {
  sum.fetch_add(i*i, std::memory_order_relaxed);
});


std::for_each(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&](int i) {
thread_pool_->queue_work(callAddFn, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thread pool version is queueing `std::ranges::size(v)` tiny pieces of work, whereas the execution policy version is given latitude to decide a reasonable chunk size.

Because you are specifying one of the unsequenced policies, your program is ill formed if `std::atomic<int>::is_lock_free()` is false. On an appropriate platform, you'd get vectorised operations implementing it.